# solving two equations with two variables. one of the equations is nonlinear

Tags: r, variables, equation

I have a system of two equations:

```
(1+x)-(x-1)*y=1.706873
((x-1)*(x-2)*y^2)-3*(x^2-1)*y+(x+1)*(2*x+1) = 4.039665
```

and I'd like to find the value of x and y. I tried to find them using this code:

```r
install.packages('nleqslv')
library(nleqslv)

f1 <- function(d) {
  f <- numeric(2)
  x <- d[1]
  y <- d[2]
  f[1] <- (1+x)*(x-1)*y - 1.706873
  f[2] <- (x-1)*(x-2)*y^2 - 3*(x^2-1)*y + (x+1)*(2*x+1) - 4.039665
  f
}

dstart <- c(1,1)
d1 <- nleqslv(dstart,f1)
d1
```

but it provided me with x and y =0  and i don't think that's the answer. especially that the message was "Jacobian is singular (1/condition=0.0e+000) (see allowSingular option)"
. can you help me? thank you

Bellow you can find the result I got

[image]

I'm also supposed to plug the results into the loop in this other code. for x to be in 1+jj*x in pgamma and 1/y in the second part of dnbinmoial in the picture. in order to get the values of 'e' as probabilities for that loop. and then calculate the chi square value and my null hypothesis has to be 'fail to reject'. so the value of 1-chisq should be greater than .05. apparently it didn't. so I'm not sure if the problem whthing the estimation or this other code. can you help me please? thank you [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avUmY.png)

Comment: Try a different sstarting values such as `dstart -> c(2,2)`. Gives a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `optim` here:

```r
f1 <- function(d) {
  f <- numeric(2)
  x <- d[1]
  y <- d[2]
  f[1] <- (1+x)*(x-1)*y - 1.706873
  f[2] <- (x-1)*(x-2)*y^2 - 3*(x^2-1)*y + (x+1)*(2*x+1) - 4.039665
  sum(abs(f))
}

optim(c(1, 1), f1)$par
#> [1] 1.467127 1.481067
```

Note though that this only gives one out of 5 solutions. The others are

```r
optim(c(-2, 0), f1)$par
#> [1] -2.7621729  0.2574625

optim(c(-2, 1), f1)$par
#> [1] -1.7361908  0.8473531

optim(c(0, -2), f1)$par
#> [1] -0.2205702 -1.7941611

optim(c(1, -4), f1)$par
#> [1]  0.7518069 -3.9257743
```

You can see the working over at [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+simultaneously+%281%2Bx%29*%28x-1%29*y+-+1.706873+%3D+0%2C+%28x-1%29*%28x-2%29*y%5E2+-+3*%28x%5E2-1%29*y+%2B+%28x%2B1%29*%282*x%2B1%29+-+4.039665+%3D+0)

Comment: thank you so much. can I ask why did we use abs(f)?

Comment: We are trying to find the minimum of the function, so if we want to find the point where both f[1] and f[2] are 0, we need to find the point when the sum of their absolute value is 0.

Comment: I'm also supposed to plug the results into the loop in this other code. for x to be in 1+jj*x in pgamma and 1/y in the second part of dnbinmoial in the picture. in order to get the values of 'e' as probabilities for that loop. and then calculate the chi square value and my null hypothesis has to be 'fail to reject'. so the value of 1-pchisq should be greater than .05. apparently it didn't. so I'm not sure if the problem with the estimation or this other code. can you help me please? thank you. i uploaded the code above. I'd really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You can find all solutions by using the function `searchZeros` from package `nleqslv`.
Do something like this

```
f1 <- function(d) {
  f <- numeric(2)
  x <- d[1]
  y <- d[2]
  f[1] <- (1+x)*(x-1)*y - 1.706873
  f[2] <- (x-1)*(x-2)*y^2 - 3*(x^2-1)*y + (x+1)*(2*x+1) - 4.039665
  f
}

set.seed(123)
N <- 100
xstart <-  matrix(runif(N,min=-3, max=3),ncol=2)
searchZeros(xstart,f1)
```

I won't show the full output since it is quite large.
Only the solutions found which are

```
$x
       [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -2.7621729  0.2574625
[2,] -1.7361908  0.8473531
[3,] -0.2205702 -1.7941611
[4,]  0.7518069 -3.9257743
[5,]  1.4671269  1.4810673
```